# How to play audio in Three JS

Tags: audio, three.js

I have some problems with Three.js audio and everything related.

How do you make an .mp3 file to play when you open the page in Three js? I haven't found any examples, any tutorial, any nothing, just nothing anywhere. I have following code:

```
var listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
camera.add( listener );

// create a global audio source
var sound = new THREE.Audio( listener );

var audioLoader = new THREE.AudioLoader();

//Load a sound and set it as the Audio object's buffer
audioLoader.load( 'sounds/ambient.ogg', function( buffer ) {
    sound.setBuffer( buffer );
    sound.setLoop(true);
    sound.setVolume(0.5);
    sound.play();
});
```

How do I make it play?

Comment: _"I haven't found any examples"_ [Seriously?](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=audio#webaudio_sandbox)

Comment: Okay, thank you. So the code in that example is:

var sound4 = new THREE.Audio( listener );
    audioLoader.load( 'sounds/Project_Utopia.ogg', function( buffer ) {
     sound4.setBuffer( buffer );
     sound4.setLoop(true);
     sound4.setVolume(0.5);
     sound4.play();
    });

when my code is: 

var sound = new THREE.Audio(listener);
    audioLoader = new THREE.AudioLoader();

    audioLoader.load('sounds/sound.ogg', function (buffer) {
        sound.setBuffer(buffer);
        sound.setLoop(true);
        sound.setVolume(0.5);
        sound.play();
    });

Yet, no go.

Comment: Any messages in the browser console?

Comment: Only some texture resize nothifications, but nothing related to this. The scene actually rolls, but there just is no audio.

Comment: I didn't try it myself, but why not taking a look at the Web Audio API? Three.js might not be the best library to do audio in the browser... This is where I would start: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro

Answer (score 1):

Try this link https://codepen.io/EllenProbst/pen/RQQmJK, below I have removed most of the JavaScript code that was not necessary to make the audio play.
It works with m4a, but it should work for mp3 and ogg formats as well.

```
// Music by The War On Drugs - Thinking Of A Place

var camera, scene, renderer;

var stream = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/ellenprobst/web-audio-api-with-Threejs/57582104/lib/TheWarOnDrugs.m4a";

// init
function init() {
    // scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0x01131e, 0.025);

    // camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(55, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0.1, -0.14, 0.8);

    // renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    
    renderer.setClearColor("#01131E");
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // AUDIO
    var audioLoader = new THREE.AudioLoader();
    var listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
    var audio = new THREE.Audio(listener);
    audioLoader.load(stream, function(buffer) {
        audio.setBuffer(buffer);
        audio.setLoop(true);
        audio.play();
    });


}


// animate
function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}

// render
function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
animate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include:

```html
// onProgress callback
function ( xhr ) {
console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
},
// onError callback
function ( err ) {
console.log( 'Un error ha ocurrido' );
}
```

So your code will be:

```html
var listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
camera.add( listener );

// create a global audio source
var sound = new THREE.Audio( listener );

var audioLoader = new THREE.AudioLoader();

//Load a sound and set it as the Audio object's buffer
audioLoader.load( 'sounds/ambient.ogg', function( buffer ) {
    sound.setBuffer( buffer );
    sound.setLoop(true);
    sound.setVolume(0.5);
    sound.play();
},
            // onProgress callback
            function ( xhr ) {
                console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
            },

            // onError callback
            function ( err ) {
                console.log( 'Un error ha ocurrido' );
            }

);
```